# Reading an image from database and storing it into another

Tags: c#, sql

I am writing a c# console application to Read Some data from one database make some changes to it and copy it to another database all the data is getting copied as expected except images.

My code is like this;

```
private static DataTable ExecuteQueryAndGetDataTableForMultiSiteDB(string query, SqlConnection ConnectionToMultiSiteDB, SqlTransaction Transaction)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(query, ConnectionToMultiSiteDB,Transaction);
        DataTable Result = new DataTable();
        SqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
        Result.Load(Reader);
        return Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occured while executing the query \n " + query);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Everything is going fine but the images are not getting copied completely, Only a part of the image data like this is getting copied = 0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D

Where as the actual image is like a million characters long, I guess this is happening because the column of each datatable that i am using has a certain limit can somebody help me overcome this situation?

Comment: What data type is the field the images are stored in, and what is the "query" string?

Comment: the `query` is a simple "Select * from SomeTable"

Comment: What is datatype?
Proabably you will need to convert it back.
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Comment: When I've done similar things, we had to handle the images in special ways.  Such as reading that field out by itself into a Byte[].

Comment: not directly related, but memory consumption may be an issue depending on the number of records and image sizes. streaming/iterating the results (IEnumerable) 1 by 1 can help alleviate part of this, rather than loading everything into memory at once (DataTable).

Comment: this example can help http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-images-gridview-from-database.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a system where you are reading a large volume of data, either from Blob or VarBinary fields, it is always best to use a DataReader, rather than a DataAdapter (as Jason stated earlier)

Also, depending on the source database, you should also specify the columns.

Using "*" is lazy and can also cause issues when reading from Jet Databases (ie: MS Access and the like) where Blob and Memo fields are truncated unless they are selected as the LAST columns.

It would be much better to iterate through each row for the image data, especially if the images are more than a few KB in size.

If you update the question with the table structure (and database type), I'll amend this answer with more information for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @KaraokeStu i changed the architecture of my application slightly now i am sending in a query that fetches one record at a time and its getting the job done seamlessly. I Appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Hi @VishweshwarKapse, no problem - please mark this as an answer if you feel it helped.